# EIP2981 implementation error

Tags: solidity, truffle, hardhat, brownie, eip

I understood that EIP2981 requires the function royaltyInfo override in my smart contract.
I wrote it that way:

```
function royaltyInfo(uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _salePrice)
        external
        view
        override
        returns (address receiver, uint256 royaltyAmount)
    {
        return (_recipient, (_salePrice * 1000) / 10000);
    }
```

But when I compile, it says that I didn't use _tokenId. from that point I thought I should delete the required _tokenId paramter, but whenever I do it there is another error saying that I didnt implement that IEIP2981 and specifies that function:

```
function royaltyInfo(uint256 tokenId, uint256 salePrice)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, you're going to need to stick with this compiler warning. It's worth pointing out that this is a warning, not an error.

To go into more detail, `_tokenId` is required by 2981 so that a contract can have a variable rate for different NFTs on the contract. This isn't necessary if you're making one constant rate for all NFTs on the contract, but will still be necessary to add in since any marketplace will call the function with a `_tokenId` since they're following the 2981 standard.

A similar error often comes up as a result of IERC721Receiver too. `onERC721Receiver` takes arguments, also to allow for more custom logic around specific NFTs which is usually not implemented. You'll get a warning for unused arguments, but you can't get rid of them and still be following the standard.

Comment: Thank you very much! helped a lot.